# Clang Tutorial Compilation Error

Tags: clang, tokenize, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, libclang

Like every new guy am trying to build something with Clang, using the tutorials found here:

[Ioarabia Clang Tutorials](https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial/wiki/TutorialOrig)

I can build the 1st and 2nd tutorial using this command:

```
export CLANG_LIBS="-lclangTooling -lclangFrontendTool -lclangFrontend -lclangDriver -lclangSerialization -lclangCodeGen -lclangParse -lclangSema -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangAnalysis -lclangARCMigrate -lclangRewrite -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangEdit -lclangAST -lclangLex -lclangBasic -lclang"
```

and compiling with:

```
g++ `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags ` tool.cpp $CLANG_LIBS `llvm-config --libs --system-libs` -o tool
```

it works!. When I move onto tutorial 3 using the same command i get the following error:

```
tutorial3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: tutorial3.cpp:85:24: error:
 invalid initialization of reference of type 
 ‘const clang::PCHContainerReader&’ from expression of type
 ‘clang::FrontendOptions’
         frontendOptions);
                         ^ In file included from tutorial3.cpp:18:0: /usr/local/include/clang/Frontend/Utils.h:66:6: note: in passing argument 3 of ‘void
clang::InitializePreprocessor(clang::Preprocessor&, const
clang::PreprocessorOptions&, const clang::PCHContainerReader&, const
clang::FrontendOptions&)’  void InitializePreprocessor(Preprocessor
&PP, const PreprocessorOptions &PPOpts,
```

Please can anybody help me? Furthermore are there any know groups of clang users? I tried google groups but didn't found any! Thanks

Comment: Please include the error message in your question *as text*, not as a screenshot.